# Programmatically click on a menu item

Tags: swift, uimenu

```
var menuList = [
    UIAction(title: "title1", handler: { (action: UIAction) in self.myAction(action) }),
    UIAction(title: "title2", handler: { (action: UIAction) in self.myAction(action) }),
    UIAction(title: "title3", handler: { (action: UIAction) in self.myAction(action) }),
]

self.btn.menu = UIMenu(children: menuList)
```

This is a drop-down button group and I need to populate the button with the title showing the item, and the check mark next to it.

How to click on the 2nd menu item programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the menu item to have the on state you would set `state` to `.on`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaction/3335178-state

```
menuList[1].state = .on
```

but this is not equivalent to clicking on the menu item, you would need code in `self.myAction` to toggle the item's state on and off.